# Как проверить ширину каждого элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

подскажите как проверить ширину bar, и если она например меньше нужного значения добавить к этому элементу класс а остальные оставить как есть. Попытался через $(this) не получилось.

```
<div class='wrp'>
  <div class='bar' style='width: 1%'>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='wrp'>
  <div class='bar' style='width: 19%'>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='wrp'>
  <div class='bar' style='width: 54%'>
  </div>
</div>

var bar = $(this).closest('.wrp').find('.bar').width();

if(bar > 20) {
    bar.addClass('reverse');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы задаёте ширину элементов в процентах. Но при расчётах js будет оперировать пикселями. И сравнение будет только по пикселям. К тому же надо понимать, от какой ширины какого объекта мы берём процент? Для примера возьмём ширину вьюпорта.

```js
let $bar = $('.bar'),
  windowWidth = $(window).width(),
  prstg = 20;
$bar.each(function() {
  console.log($(this).width());
  if ($(this).width() < (windowWidth * prstg)) {
    $(this).addClass('reverse');
  }
});
```

```css
.bar{height:50px;border:1px solid #000}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrp'><div class='bar' style='width: 1%'></div></div>
<div class='wrp'><div class='bar' style='width: 19%'></div></div>
<div class='wrp'><div class='bar' style='width: 54%'></div></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а почему инициализация через let?

Comment: https://medium.com/@vkozulya/es2015-на-пальцах-var-let-и-const-d194b902cfc0

Answer (score 1):

```js
// достаем все элементы .bar
var allBars = $('.bar');

// Пробегаемся циклом по ним и проверяем ширину
allBars.each(function() {
  let w = $(this).width();

  if (w > 20) $(this).addClass('red');
  else $(this).addClass('green');
  console.log(w);
});
```

```css
.bar {
  height: 10px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrp'>
  <div class='bar' style='width: 1%'>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='wrp'>
  <div class='bar' style='width: 19%'>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='wrp'>
  <div class='bar' style='width: 54%'>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JQuery.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/)